# Fluid flowing through linked obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation, linked-data

I have linked an object from another .blend file that has fluid obstacle physics. I have an inflow fluid object flowing onto it and a fluid domain object surrounding it.

However, the fluid simply flows through the linked obstacle object. Are there any properties I need to tweak or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Fluids ignore the linked object but you can create a proxy of the object and make that a fluid obstacle.  Sorry.
Hopefully, unlike me, you've moved on by now, and this isn't the worst news you've had all week.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your cup and go to the physics tab and under "Volume Initialization" and select both.

A good tutorial to follow is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgwKPP2ZEjI

Hope I helped!